# How to override route based on condition when application has multi-store functionality

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, nopcommerce

We are using nopCommerce. We've override category page route in plugin. its working fine. But we want to override only for one store not for second store.

As per my review all the route are registered when application restart. So not sure how to make conditional route in mvc or nopcommerce.

Question related to: [Click Here](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/41828/store-wise-route-from-custom-plugin.aspx)

Comment: No. I tried but not working. did you try ?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the way to go is to provide a custom route constraint (a class implementing `IRouteConstraint`), and use it when declaring your routes.

NopCommerce has one created you can use as an example. Check the [`GuidConstraint`](https://github.com/nuodb/nopCommerce/blob/c4d3ec3d74b0a5bf45ca00ad8fe3f85bcbcbfb65/Presentation/Nop.Web.Framework/Mvc/Routes/GuidConstraint.cs) class.